# jQuery unobtrusive validation in partial view loaded multiple times only works for first view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I have a partial view that is loaded multiple times into a view and validation only works on the first occurence. I have tried the standard solution (`$.validator.unobtrusive.parse`) with all it's variants, but it just doesn't work.

If I, however, make the name of each field unique (by adding a fake prefix to the input name) the validation works, but then the value returned in my model is always null. I assume this is because the framework doesn't know how to handle the value with a fake prefix.

Is there some way to solve the problem without using a fake prefix? If not, what do I need to do to get the correct value into my model and the action method?

Answer (score -1):

I had somehow same problem using jquery validation on multiple partial views in a single view. I solved my problem by using class attribute and by avoiding using unique identifiers on the partial views.

Comment: Please improve your answer with some code samples or something like that.